# Multivariate detrending under common trend of a time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for multivariate detrending under common trend of a time series data in R.

Time series data sample:

```
> head(d)
  T x1 x2 x3 x4
1 1  2  4  3  1
2 2  3  5  4  4
3 3  6  6  6  6
4 4  8  9  10 7
5 5  10 13 20 9
```

I would like to detrend the above multivariate time series dataset d under common trend. I hope I am clear in explaining the problem that I am facing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multivariate regression to solve for constants.  Because the betas are the same, (i.e. beta in Y=x*beta is an n by 2 matrix with identical rows), you need to account for that constraint.  However, you can just string all the Ys together for this.

```
dvec=as.numeric(d)
n=dim(d)[1]
ncol=dim(d)[2]
x=rep(1:n,ncol)
model<-lm(dvec~x)
```

Then you can do

```
d=matrix(model$residuals,nrow=n)
```

Comment: I have came across the packages "pracma", which removes the mean value or (piecewise) linear trend from a vector or from each column of a matrix. `detrend(x, tt = 'linear', bp = c())`, where x can be a matrix. But it detrends each column of the matrix x. I dont think the function detrend() detrends under the common trend of the multivariate time series dataframe.